# JFreeChart: how to scale Y-axis when time axis is reduced?

Tags: java, scale, jfreechart, yaxis

I have created a plot in JFreeChart, consisting of a `TimeSeriesCollection` and `XYPlot`. The horizontal axis uses a `DateAxis`, and the vertical (Y) axis is using a `NumberAxis`. If the horizontal axis is using all dates for which I have data points I get a proper Y-axis scale when using:

```
Y1axis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
Y1axis.setRangeWithMargins(LeftSeries.getRangeBounds(true));
```

Now I want to create a plot from only a portion of the available time data. For example: I have data points covering four years, but want to create a plot of only the second year. For this I create a date range (`MinDate` is the oldest data point I want to show, `MaxDate` the most recent data point I want to show):

```
dateAxis.setMinimumDate(MinDate);
dateAxis.setMaximumDate(MaxDate);
```

This scales the horizontal axis as desired. However, if I now use the same code to scale the Y axis (`Y1axis.setRangeWithMargins(LeftSeries.getRangeBounds(true))`) I get the entire vertical range, suitable for the entire data set. What I want is a vertical scale which suits the date range `MinDate`~`MaxDate`.
I have tried a few things to get the vertical axis to scale correctly, but none of my attempts was any good. For example:

```
double LowValue = Y1axis.getLowerBound();
double HighValue = Y1axis.getUpperBound();
Y1axis.setRange(LowValue, HighValue);
```

did not work.
What code should I use to adjust the scale on the vertical (Y) axis to adapt itself to the horizontal time axis data points which are shown in the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to enable *auto range* for the `Y1axis` axis:

```
Y1axis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
Y1axis.setAutoRange(true);
```

Example:

All data:

[image]

Subset of values with auto range *disabled*:

[image]

Subset of values with auto range *enabled*:

[image]

Comment: So obvious but somehow I overlooked this. Thank you Topaco, as it answered my question.